# ATP stoichiometry of the Na+/K+ pump

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, cell-membrane, bioenergetics, membrane-transport

The Na+/K+ ATPase pump exports 3 Na+ for every 2 Ka+ imported. This process is ATP dependent, but I have not been able to find *how many* ATPs are required in each translocation. What is the stoichiometric ATP cost of this reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sodium/potassium-exchanging ATPase (EC 3.6.3.9)](https://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/3.6.3.9):

> An enzyme from the plasma membrane of animal cells that catalyzes the efflux of three Na(+) and influx of two K(+) per ATP hydrolyzed.

You can read about the [mechanism on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%2B/K%2B-ATPase#Mechanism):

> - The pump, after binding ATP, binds 3 intracellular Na+
>     ions.
> - ATP is hydrolyzed, leading to phosphorylation of the pump at a highly conserved aspartate residue and subsequent release of ADP.
> - A conformational change in the pump exposes the Na+
>     ions to the outside. The phosphorylated form of the pump has a low affinity for Na+ ions, so they are released.
> - The pump binds 2 extracellular K+ ions. This causes the dephosphorylation of the pump, reverting it to its previous conformational state, transporting the K+
>     ions into the cell.
> - The unphosphorylated form of the pump has a higher affinity for Na+
>     ions than K+
>     ions, so the two bound K+
>     ions are released. ATP binds, and the process starts again.

Comment: So the stoichiometry is 3 Na+ exported, 2 K+ imported, 1 ATP hydrolyzed. Thanks.