# Can the Na+/K+ pump backwards to generate ATP?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, cell-membrane, bioenergetics, membrane-transport

The standard physiological direction of the Na+/K+ pump is to export 3 Na+, import 2 K+, and hydrolyze one ATP to ADP. Can it be driven backwards, importing 3 Na+, exporting 2 K+, and generating ATP? Does this happen in normal cells, and in what conditions?

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/67418/561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All enzymes can theoretically catalyze the reverse reaction](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59246/6307).

[Researchers have driven the Na<sup>+</sup>/K<sup>+</sup> ATPase to synthesize ATP with artificial ion concentrations](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v269/n5624/abs/269165a0.html):

> We have studied the apparent affinity for K at its intracellular discharge sites by measuring the rate of ATP synthesis as a function of the internal K concentration in resealed red blood cell ghosts, where the Na-K pump is driven in reverse by the downhill efflux of K and influx of Na…

Comment: But does it happen physiologically, or for cells in culture?

Comment: @becko Oh sorry, I didn't see that part of your question. In the paper they drove the reaction with a very high ADP/ATP ratio which I expect wouldn't be found in cells. Technically it is possible for this reverse reaction to occur physiologically, but the ATPase activity will be dominant.

Comment: So it seems that the answer is No. I'll wait a bit more before accepting your answer. Thanks again.